#  Почему не работает код простой "читалки"?

Tags: flutter

```html
import "package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart";

import "package:flutter/material.dart";

import "dart:async";

import "dart:io";

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

getIntSF() async {

  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  
  int numbP = prefs.getInt('numbPage') ?? 0;
  
  return numbP;
}

int numbPage = getIntSF();

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  final contr = ScrollController();
  
  final Bloc bloc = Bloc();
  
  @override
  
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  
    return MaterialApp(
    
      title: 'Бла Бла',
      
      theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.green),
      
      home: Scaffold(
      
          appBar: AppBar(
          
              title: StreamBuilder(
              
                initialData: numbPage,
                
                stream: bloc.press,
                
                builder: (context, snapshot) => Text(
                
                    'Бла Бла  ${snapshot.data.toString()}',
                    
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0)),
                    
              ),
              
              actions: <Widget>[
              
                IconButton(
                
                    icon: Icon(Icons.exit_to_app),
                    
                    tooltip: 'Выйти из приложения',
                    
                    onPressed: () {
                    
                      addIntToSF();
                      
                      exit(0);
                      
                    })
                    
              ]),
              
          body: Center(
          
              child: Column(
              
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  
                  children: <Widget>[
                  
                StreamBuilder(
                
                    initialData: book[numbPage],
                    
                    stream: bloc.txt,
                    
                    builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    
                      return Expanded(
                      
                          child: SingleChildScrollView(
                          
                              controller: contr,
                              
                              child: Text('${snapshot.data}',
                              
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                  
                                      fontSize: 20.0,
                                      
                                      fontStyle: FontStyle.italic))));
                                      
                    })
                    
              ])),
              
          bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
          
              shape: CircularNotchedRectangle(),
              
              child: Container(height: 50.0)),
              
          floatingActionButton: Container(
          
              width: 50.0,
              
              height: 50.0,
              
              child: FloatingActionButton(
              
                  onPressed: () {
                  
                    bloc.butPres.add(numbPage);
                    
                    contr.jumpTo(0.0);
                    
                  },
                  
                  tooltip: 'Бла Бла',
                  
                  child: Icon(Icons.add))),
                  
          floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.endDocked),
          
    );
    
  }

  addIntToSF() async {
  
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    
    prefs.setInt('numbPage', numbPage);
    
  }
  
}

class Bloc {

  Bloc() {
  
    _contrIn.stream.listen((data) {
    
      numbPage++;

      _contrOut.add(numbPage);

      _contrOutTxt.add(book[numbPage]);
      
    });
    
  }

  get butPres => _contrIn;

  var _contrIn = StreamController<int>();

  var _contrOut = StreamController<int>();

  get press => _contrOut.stream;

  var _contrOutTxt = StreamController();

  get txt => _contrOutTxt.stream;

  void dispose() {
  
    _contrIn.close();
    
    _contrOut.close();
    
    _contrOutTxt.close();
    
  }
}

List book = [
  "мама",
  "папа",
  "бабушка",
  "дедушка",
  "сын",
  "дочь",
];
```

Ожидалось, что код будет читать из шаред преференсес значение переменной, а после выхода из приложения сохранять его туда же. При следующем старте на экране должна отображаться бывшей последней в предыдущей сессии строка, например "мама".

Comment: 1) Потому что `async`. У вас данные не успевают доставаться, а вы их уже используете (точнее их `null`). 2) Вы пытаетесь достать их синхронно...

Comment: Если это не сильно сложно, подскажите как сделать правильно?

Comment: добавил пример.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример с `singleton`:

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State {
  var savedString = '';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Shared Preferences'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(20).add(EdgeInsets.only(top: 20)),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            RaisedButton(
              onPressed: (){
                StorageUtil.putString("myString", "My stored string in shared preferences");
              },
              textColor: Colors.white,
              color: Colors.red,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: new Text(
                "Save String",
              ),
            ),
            Text(savedString, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),),
            SizedBox(height: 60,),
            RaisedButton(
              onPressed: (){
                setState(() {
                  savedString = StorageUtil.getString("myString");
                });
              },
              textColor: Colors.white,
              color: Colors.red,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: new Text(
                "Get String",
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class StorageUtil {
  static StorageUtil _storageUtil;
  static SharedPreferences _preferences;

  static Future getInstance() async {
    if (_storageUtil == null) {
      var secureStorage = StorageUtil._();
      await secureStorage._init();
      _storageUtil = secureStorage;
    }
    return _storageUtil;
  }

  StorageUtil._();

  Future _init() async {
    _preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  }

  // получаем
  static String getString(String key, {String defValue = ''}) {
    if (_preferences == null) return defValue;
    return _preferences.getString(key) ?? defValue;
  }

  // записываем
  static Future putString(String key, String value) {
    if (_preferences == null) return null;
    return _preferences.setString(key, value);
  }
}
```